# How do I turn this string into a list efficiently (Android)?

Tags: java, android

I've been writing this Android program where at first, you need to write in a few names, email addresses and phone numbers, and I have this string that I need to turn into a list to be able to display it in ListView. I've looked up a lot of things and they all turned out differently and not the way I wanted them to.

Here's the part where the string is taken up (as a JSONObject and then JSONArray), so that you can see what it looks like:

```
public static void addFriend(Context c, String name, String number, String email) {
    try {
        if (friends == null) {
            friends = new JSONObject();
            friends.put("array", new JSONArray());
        }

        JSONArray array = friends.getJSONArray("array");

        JSONObject friend = new JSONObject();

        friend.put("name", name);
        friend.put("phone number", number);
        friend.put("email", email);
        array.put(friend);





        FileOutputStream fos = c.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(friends.toString().getBytes());
        fos.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And here's the part where it's read:

```
public static void printAllBytes(Context c){
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = c.openFileInput(FILENAME);
        String readedBytes = new String(readAllBytes(fis), "UTF-8");

        System.err.println(readedBytes);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And the result printed by the "System.err.println(readedBytes)" is:

```
{"array":[{"name":"le on","phone number":"1337","email":"leon"}]}
```

(I typed in a random name, email and phonenumber, to test it). 
I know that typing in multiple things after another adds them to the array, that's part of the point, but when it comes to putting the items into a list, I'm just stumped. I don't want to do it with a for-loop, that seems much to inefficient to me.

Thanks in advance :)
-Léon

Comment: why don't you create a Class of Person with all the variables and then add the instances of Person to list ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider storing the variables into an object rather than JSON.

```
public class Person {
    String mName;
    String mNumber;
    String mEmail;
}
```

Once you do that you can create an ArrayAdapter which takes your object and maps it to a custom XML.

This article provides much more detail on how ListViews work: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html.